# Black diamond question mark coming on page

Tags: javascript, windows, jsp, tomcat, extjs4.1

Hi I am getting a black diamond with a white color question mark in one of my jsp where I use ExtJs grid to show the data.

I am having two different machines(windows machine) on which i run my application.

Machine 1 has its own tomcat

Machine 2 has its own tomcat

Both the machines are pointing to same database & the webapp(jsp,javascript etc) files that are present on both the machines tomcat are also same.

When I open the page in browser by pointing to machine 1 then I am getting the black color diamond with a question mark.
But it doesnt happen on the Machine 2.

I know this problem is caused due to the character encoding but as my webapp files are same on both the machines, I am unable to figure out where the problem is ? Is it in the files or in the tomcat or in the operating system(windows)

Please help me out to understand and resolve the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is special character in your text which is causing the problem. i have faced the same problem try checking the single apostrophe(`) or quotes like and also check for document charset in metatag it should be utf-8.

Comment: There is not single apostrophe in the text but there are only spaces at the end which are getting converted to black diamond question mark. Here is the text -


"This is the text             "



And on both the machines the jsp has following cahrtset in the meta tag -

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">